# Express/Mongo can push new data, but unable to update existing data

Tags: mongodb, express

I have an Express/Mongo backend and am trying to update data "manually".

I call `UserObj.findById(req.params.id, function(err,doc){... callback ...})`

And in the callback function, I update the document. I'm able to `push` new data into the `doc` query result (and then into the Mongo DB), but if I try to update existing data in `doc`, while it shows in my `console.log` that `doc` has been updated, when I look in the Mongo DB, the data hasn't actually been updated.

Is this default behavior by Mongo, or am I making a mistake somewhere? If this is default behavior, what's the best work around? I'm trying to avoid using the built-in `findByIdAndUpdate` functions, because I'm hoping to have more manual control over how I treat each field. (For instance, for certain fields I want to `push` new data, and other fields I want to `update` the existing data).

Here are the relevant portions from the controller call-back (`users_controller.user_details_update`):

```
    exports.user_details_post = [(req, res, next)=> {
        //LOG, VALIDATE, SANITIZE
. . . 
. . .         
        //SAVE
        (req,res, next) =>{
            const errors = validationResult(req);

            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                // Handle Validation Errors
            } else {
                let user = UserObj.findById(req.params.id, function(err,doc){
                    let activeArr = [];
                    let maxActive = 0;
    
                    if (err) {}
                    Object.keys(doc["_doc"]).forEach(sec=>{
                       Object.keys(doc["_doc"][sec]["_doc"]).filter(fld=>doc["_doc"][sec]["_doc"][fld].hasOwnProperty("value")).forEach(fld=> {
                         activeArr = [];
                         maxActive = +doc["_doc"][sec]["_doc"][fld]["attr"]["active"].reduce((acc,cur)=>Math.max(acc, cur),-Infinity);
                         Object.keys(req.body).filter(reqFld=>
                                        new RegExp(`^${fld}__${sec}--[0-9]*-[0-9]*`).test(reqFld)).forEach(reqFld=> {
                           let activeVal = +reqFld.split(SEC_SPLIT_CHAR)[1].split(ROW_SPLIT_CHAR)[1];
                           if (activeVal > maxActive) {
                             doc["_doc"][sec]["_doc"][fld]["value"].push(req.body[reqFld])  // THIS    
                                                                                           // WORKS FINE
                           } else if (activeVal===maxActive) {
                             doc["_doc"][sec]["_doc"][fld]["value"][0]=req.body[reqFld]  // NO ERRORS 
                                                                              // THROWN, BUT THE 
                                                                              // DOCUMENT DOESN'T GET 
                                                                              // UPDATED IN MONGODB
 . . . 
 . . .                    
                   // SAVE
                    doc.save(function(err){  // SAVE WORKS OK. NO ERRORS
                        if (err) { return next(err);}
                    });
                    console.log("redirecting . . . ")
                    res.redirect("http://localhost:4200/");  // EXITS NORMALLY
                });
            }
        },
    ];
```

Also, when I examine the `doc` object in the callback, I see that it contains some "added" fields `["_doc"]` in the top two levels of the object hierarchy. Could my issues have anything to do with how I'm dealing with these "extra" fields? Or am I stuck with having to create a brand new user Object, writing updated data into that object, and then copying over the `_id`'s from the old object? (Seems somewhat wasteful to have to do it that way).

### Update

I haven't been able to find another way yet, except to copy the updated `doc` into a new `UserObj`, remove the old `UserObj`, and then switch the `_id` on the new user to the old user's `_id`, as below:

```
. . . 
. . . 

                    thisUser = doc;

                });
                user.remove().then(result=>{
                    sameUser = new UserObj(thisUser);
                    sameUser._id = thisUser._id;
                },err=>next(err)).then(result=>{
                    sameUser.save(err=>{
                        console.log("Saving DETAILS . . . ")
                        if (err) { return next(err);}
                        console.log("Saved DETAILS . . . Now redirecting ");
                        res.redirect("http://localhost:4200/");
    
                    })
                })
```

Personally, while it works, I find this solution slightly kludgey and somewhat inelegant. I'd be open to a better solution.

Comment: In the following link, it indicates I should be able to do what I want to do, but is there a problem doing this for nested fields? <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose>. Here's the specific code in the link: `console.log(awesome_instance.name); //should log 'also_awesome'

// Change record by modifying the fields, then calling save().
awesome_instance.name="New cool name";
awesome_instance.save(function (err) {
   if (err) return handleError(err); // saved!
});
`

Comment: I'm getting kind of desperate. I even tried something as cheeky as: "                                               UserObj.update({_id: doc.id},JSON.parse(\`{${sec}.${fld}: '${req.body[reqFld]}'}\`))" but that didn't work